# jQuery ajax call - don't wait until requested page is loaded, display it immediately

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am working on a wordpress plugin that uses an ajax call to display results on the current page. The call is made to a php file which uses ob_end_flush() and ob_start() to output each line as it is processed.

My problem is, when I include this file with the ajax call, it seems that jquery first waits until the entire page is fully processed before it is displayed. I would like that the file is displayed immediately and then outputs line by line just like it is suppose to.

jquery file

```
jQuery("#analyze").click(function(){

    jurl=jQuery("#url").val();

    jQuery.ajax({
        beforeSend: function() {
            jQuery('#loading_bar').show();
            jQuery('#results').hide();
        },
        type: "POST",
        url: "/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/results.php",
        data: { 
            url:jurl
        }
    })
    .done(function(ajaxresult) {
        jQuery('#loading_bar').hide();
        jQuery('#results').show();
        jQuery("#results").html(ajaxresult);


    })
    .fail(function() {
        alert( "Error" );
    });
});
```

results.php

```
<?PHP
if(!empty($_POST['url'])) {

    $url = $_POST['url'];
    $url_info = get_url_metrics($url);

    foreach($url_info as $value) {

        ob_end_flush();
        echo "Info: :";
        echo $value;
        echo "<br />";
        ob_start();
    }
    echo "Done";
}
?>
```

Comment: i think what you want is not supported by http and the way it handles transmissions.

Comment: May I ask how something like this is created: http://99webtools.com/banklink-with-pagerank.php

It seems there is an Ajax call made as well, and then it outputs line per line as it is processed. This is what I would like to create.

Comment: Press ctrl+shift+j on it. it's sending a request for each one, one by one. The first request gets a list of sites, then for each site another request is sent to get the page rank. As they finish, they are displayed, one by one.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Thank you very much. I guess in that case, I need to rethink the way I create my plugin. Thanks again.